# Server logout failed > client only logout?

Tags: security, cookies

I have a general question. I have a web application which uses cookies for Authentication. Also the cookie is verified by the server.

But what should I do in the following scenario:

- the user clicks on the logout button
- via AJAX the logout request is send to the server
- the server is down or blocked by a hacker, so the logout request doesn't get through

The question is. what should I do now?

1. show an error message and keep the client logged in (what should I say?)
2. logout the client and show an error message (again: what should I say?)
3. logout the client and do not show any message. (In case of a hacker attack, the hacker can use the client Authentication token, because the server doesn't know anything, but the client did not notice anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you have a short session timeout, so the user will be logged out anyway after 20 minutes or so.

This is sort of opinion based but my suggestion is to clear cookies client side if possible - this is only possible if your session cookies are not httponly, which they should be. If you can't log the client out because an attacker blocks access to the logout URL then:

Yes, show an error message to keep the user informed. After all, it is their account that is at risk. Something along the lines of "You could not be logged out. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact us. It is recommended to clear your cookies."

So to answer your question, the best response is #2, however if you have session security as a priority this may not be possible, so you will have to go with #1.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. As we use JWT to be fully stateless, it is possible for us to logout on the client side. But thanks for the notice.